# PrimeFaces datatable initial sortBy does not work

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have a PrimeFaces 3.2 DataTable using apache myfaces 2.0.2 . I want a initial sort. My JSF looks like:

```
<p:dataTable  id="serverdata" var="serverdata" sortBy="#{serverdata[0]}" sortOrder="descending" 
                value="#{ serverDataTable.list }" rows="10" editable="true" 
                paginator="true" rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,50"
                paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}">
                <f:facet name="header">  
                   Datatable
                 </f:facet>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Datum"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{serverdata[0]}">
                    </h:outputText>
                </p:column>
```

But I get a `UnsupportedOperationException: The result list is read-only.` When I delete the sortBy tag in  it works fine.

So my question:
How can I realize an initial sort?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sorting is executed on the original `List`. If it is read-only, an Exception is thrown. Try the same, but with a regular, mutable `List`

EDIT : create a regular list in the bean:

```
public class MyBean {
...
List<MyObject> myList = new ArryList<MyObject>();
myList.add(new MyObject("a"));
myList.add(new MyObject("b"));
myList.add(new MyObject("c"));
...
```

then use sorting like this : `value="#{myBean.myList}" var="myVar" sortBy="#{myVar.stringProp}"`

EDIT2: If the sorting parameters are strings or numbers, you do not need to customize anything. If you are sorting anything else, you will have to define a custom sortFunction,

If you use advanced options like lazy loading (which is btw broken in pf 3.2 - you can update to 3.3 now - it has been released on 29.5 and claims to have solved this), you will have to define a custom model, taking care of filtering and sorting yourself.

So if you want to sort your data by the contents of an array, you would need to define the attribute `sortFunction="#{myBean.sortData()}"`

Comment: Ok thank you, so I need a special bean to represent my object[], right? b.t.w. the list<object[]> is a result from a jpa query

Comment: @kostja PF wants that i have a list out of SortMeta values. Can you help me with this problem ?